# Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor error coming on my controller class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

//added image

```java
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService es;

@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)    
public Employee getEmployeeByID(@PathVariable Long id)
{

    return es.getEmployeeByID(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with id :" + id));
}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Please add more info

Comment: I have added image ... actually the error was populated on EmployeeController. When i hover mouse on it , i could see Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Comment: Error you are getting on server startup or while calling the API?

Comment: Actually i just changed my java version to 1.8 from 1.7 in eclipse then this populated without server statup

Comment: " Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor" is thrown when your JRE is misconfigured in your IDE. You have to check your Java 8 configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: most probably and IDE issue, please configure you jdk/jre and build path